# Закрасить цветом дату в календаре

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, php

Всем привет!
Нужно сделать такую вещь: график работы пользователя.
Пользователь видит календарь на месяц. Кликает по нужному числу и отмечает его цветом (2 цвета). Все сохраняется "на лету".

```
var D1 = new Date(),
    D1last = new Date(D1.getFullYear(),D1.getMonth()+1,0).getDate(), // последний день месяца
    D1Nlast = new Date(D1.getFullYear(),D1.getMonth(),D1last).getDay(), // день недели последнего дня месяца
    D1Nfirst = new Date(D1.getFullYear(),D1.getMonth(),1).getDay(), // день недели первого дня месяца
    calendar1 = '<tr>',
    month=["Январь","Февраль","Март","Апрель","Май","Июнь","Июль","Август","Сентябрь","Октябрь","Ноябрь","Декабрь"]; // название месяца, вместо цифр 0-11

// пустые клетки до первого дня текущего месяца
if (D1Nfirst != 0) {
  for(var  i = 1; i < D1Nfirst; i++) calendar1 += '<td>';
}else{ // если первый день месяца выпадает на воскресенье, то требуется 7 пустых клеток 
  for(var  i = 0; i < 6; i++) calendar1 += '<td>';
}

// дни месяца
for(var  i = 1; i <= D1last; i++) {
  if (i != D1.getDate()) {
    calendar1 += '<td class="date"><a href="[[~[[*id]]]]#" onclick="change_color()">' + i;
  }else{
    calendar1 += '<td id="today">' + i;  // сегодняшней дате можно задать стиль CSS
  }
  if (new Date(D1.getFullYear(),D1.getMonth(),i).getDay() == 0) {  // если день выпадает на воскресенье, то перевод строки
    calendar1 += '<tr>';
  }
}

// пустые клетки после последнего дня месяца
if (D1Nlast != 0) {
  for(var  i = D1Nlast; i < 7; i++) calendar1 += '<td>';
}

document.querySelector('#calendar1 tbody').innerHTML = calendar1;
document.querySelector('#calendar1 thead td:last-child').innerHTML = D1.getFullYear();
document.querySelector('#calendar1 thead td:first-child').innerHTML = month[D1.getMonth()];
```

Comment: логика, разметка - все в одном месте. ужс.  

1. Напишите функцию формирования одной ячейки - дня.  
2. Напишите функцию добавления дней в таблицу календаря.  
3. Напишите обработчики действий для ячеек календаря (которые будут вызывать сохранение "на лету").  
4. Создайте массив описаний праздничных дней, по нему циклом заполняйте праздники (не забудьте, что бывают переносы праздников).  
5. Если у вас используется jquery, то зачем вам querySelector...

А вот уже потом можно говорить про сохранение на лету. Пока идийская каша.

Comment: Код исправил. Но вот что писать в функции change_color, не придумаю никак.

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/326762/jquery-выделение-ячеек-таблицы

Там же пример смотрите http://jsfiddle.net/N2EGr/

Comment: Как я понял, мы при клике меняем/добавляем класс к ячейке. А как мне потом вытащить то, что пользователь навыделял на другой странице? Ведь данные нужно как-то сохранить. А как сохранить класс ячейки? Или я все перепутал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите, здесь http://jsfiddle.net/N2EGr/ , при клике на ячейку возвращается ее содержимое (выбранное число) и закрашивается ячейка.

Замените ***alert($(this).html());*** и код смены класса на нечто вроде

```
var day = $(this).html();
var your_url = 'урл на скрипт обработки';
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: your_url,
        data: "uid=" + your_uid + "&day="+day,
        success: function(data) {
            if (data) {
                $('td').not(this).filter(function() {
                    return $(this).index() == index;
                }).removeClass('click');

                $(this).toggleClass('click');
            } else {
                // обработка ошибки соединения или еще что-либо
            }
        }
    });
```

your_url - по этому адресу будет скрипт, который получает выбранную дату (месяц/год), ид пользователя и сохраняет это в БД.

your_uid - ид текущего пользователя.

Экспериментируйте ;)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/N2EGr/1/ - почему то не возвращает значения при клике. В принципе скрипт уже похож на то, что мне нужно.
Нужно просто закрашивать при клике даты и значения дат сохранять в БД. Чтобы потом можно было вывести в другом месте, какие даты закрасил пользователь.
А также чтобы при клике еще раз, например через неделю планы изменились, захотелось убрать выходной. Кликнул по нему, он стал беленьким и как-то в БД обозначилось, что он теперь белый. Как это все сделать? Как передать что он то красный то белый - может какой статус добавить?

Comment: Сейчас вроде бы все выделяется, данные на обработчик передаются, но вот какая ситуация: Не пойму почему скрипт отрабатывает как-будто бы 2 раза. Выделение ставиться, потом тут же исчезает. Выловить смог только когда включил alert(); Он отображает значение первого клика, а потом тут же как будто-бы второй раз кликнул и выделение снимается.

Comment: Я дал неправильную ссылку на фидл, а вспомнить, что я там вчера на(ш)кодил, не вспомню. Но, судя по вашим соседним вопросам, вы уже и сами дошли до истины ;)

Comment: Да, потихоньку двигаюсь. Задам еще один вопрос, про отображение полученных результатв, помогите, пожалуйста.